# Escaping nil closure definition in Swift

Tags: swift3

In objective-C I could pass a nil completion handler to any function. Coming to Swift3 I am struggling a bit with nil closure definition. I have a function defined like this:

```
func doSomething ( completion : @escaping (Error?) -> ()? ) {
    let error = foo( completion : { (error) in 
        completion (error)
    })
}
```

Now the point is that I try to call this function with a nil parameter for completion as I do not care of the results, I just want to launch a background activity. Calling

```
doSomething ( completion : nil)
```

leads to error "nil is not compatible with type (error) -> ()?"
This was quite ok in Obj-C. I tried to google up and down but no success. I tried to relocate question mark around closure definition but not luck.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to relocate question mark around closure definition but not luck.

You don't just *relocate* the question mark. You need to add braces.

Currently, `(Error?) -> ()?` is a non-optional closure type that has these two parts:

```
(Error?)
Void?
```

As you can see, it returns an optional `Void` which isn't very helpful, is it?

The `?` associated with `()` instead of the whole closure type. To force it to associate with the whole closure type, just put braces around the stuff you want to make optional:

```
((Error?) -> ())?
```

Comment: Thing is that it does not work with escaping. I get the "escaping attribute only applies to function types" error. Putting escaping inside braces causes "escaping attribute may only be used in function parameter position" compile error.

Comment: OK seems I found it. While your example is correct one remark is required. Seems optional closures are escaping by default. No need for the escaping keyword which is frustrating a bit but it works at least.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function as below:

```
func doSomething ( completion : ((_ error: NSError?) -> Swift.Void)? ) {
    let error = foo( completion : { (error) in 
            completion?(urlString, error)
    })
}
```